# Unexpected execution in an update query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-update, updates

I am getting an 'Unexpected' result with an update query in SQL Server 2012.
This is what I am trying to do.

From a column (IDENTIFIER) composed by an `ID ','name` (e.g. 258967,Sarah Jones), I have to fill other two columns: `ID` and `SELLER_NAME`.

The original column has some values with a blank at the end  and the rest with out it:

```
'258967,Sarah Jones'
'98745,Richard James '
```

This is the update query that I am executing:

```
UPDATE SELLER
SET 
IDENTIFIER = LTRIM(RTRIM(IDENTIFIER)),
ID = Left(IDENTIFIER , charindex(',', IDENTIFIER )-1),
SELLER_NAME = UPPER(RIGHT((IDENTIFIER ),LEN(IDENTIFIER )-CHARINDEX(',',IDENTIFIER )));
```

But I am having a wrong result at the end

```
258967,Sarah Jones    258967  SARAH JONES
98745,Richard James    98745   ICHARD JAMES
```

The same happens with all the names that has the blank at the end. At this point I wonder, if I have specified that I want to eliminate all the blanks at the begining and at the end of the value of IDENTIFIER as a first action, why the system updates the ID and SELLER_NAMES and then does this action?.

**Just to specify**: The IDENTIFIER column is part of the seller table which is updating from another person that imports the data from an Excel file. I receive this values and I have to normalize the information. I only can read the SELLER table, take this into account before answer

Comment: This is what you get for having a lousy table design. If your design was properly normalized, each of those values would have its own field, and you wouldn't be stuck trying to update values with string operations. consider how much easier it'd be to `update seller set name='fred' where name='sarah'` than all that charindex/len/right garbage.

Comment: There's something you're not telling us.  There is no way the 'Richar' in '98745,Richar James ' is being transformed by your code into anything containing the substring 'ICHARD'

Comment: Do you get the same results if you do the `SET IDENTIFIER = LTRIM(RTRIM(IDENTIFIER)` first on a separate update and then set the `ID` and `SELLER_NAME`? I'm thinking the `IDENTIFIER` column might still have the trailing space when setting the `SELLER_NAME` and that this could mess up the parsing.

Comment: Good move splitting out that `IDENTIFIER`, by the way. It will make managing that table much more straight forward.

Comment: If you need to use all those string functions,use them to normalize your db.

Comment: I have added the clarification in the question. however, I still have the same doubt: why the LTRIM(RTRIM()) is not done before to update the other two columns?

Comment: I think it is because all 3 updates happen at once, so your `IDENTIFIER` column is not trimmed yet when you are setting the `ID` and `SELLER` values.

Comment: Untill UPDATE operation finished, you dont have updated value of IDENTIFIER to use, thats why LTRIM(RTRIM()) not set the value. Either you have to use two separate queries to do that, first update IDENTIFIER, then UPDATE other two column

Answer (score 5):

Try this, because you have space in right side of name, so it will just truncate one char from name.  So just need to `RTRIM(IDENTIFIER)` and thats it.

```
SELLER_NAME = UPPER(RIGHT((RTRIM(IDENTIFIER)),LEN(IDENTIFIER )-CHARINDEX(',',IDENTIFIER)));
```

Comment: That is why I have done this operation with IDENTIFIER. However, I still have the same doubt: why the LTRIM(RTRIM()) is not done before to update the other two columns?

Comment: Untill UPDATE operation finished, you dont have updated value of IDENTIFIER to use, thats why LTRIM(RTRIM()) not set the value. Either you have to use two separate queries to do that, first update IDENTIFIER, then UPDATE other two column

Answer (score 1):

The design of your tables violates 1NF and is nothing but painful. Instead of doing all this crazy string manipulation you could leverage PARSENAME here quite easily.

```
with Something(SomeValue) as
(
    select '258967,Sarah Jones' union all
    select '98745,Richard James '
)

select *
    , ltrim(rtrim(PARSENAME(replace(SomeValue, ',', '.'), 2)))
    , ltrim(rtrim(PARSENAME(replace(SomeValue, ',', '.'), 1)))
from Something
```

Comment: +1 Nice use of ParseName! The only caveat for OP is that if a persons name contains a period e.g. "Dr. Jones" this won't work.

Comment: I have added the clarification in the question. However, I still have the same doubt: why the LTRIM(RTRIM()) is not done before to update the other two columns?

Comment: Agreed about having existing commas in the name, of course the original query didn't account for that either. Would be easy enough to do a couple of additional replaces to swap them around.

Answer (score 0):

try trim the IDENTIFIER first like this

```
SALLER_NAME = UPPER(RIGHT((RTRIM(IDENTIFIER),LEN(IDENTIFIER )-CHARINDEX(',',IDENTIFIER )));
```

Comment: There is no TRIM() function in MSSQL till 2014 Version

Comment: I have added the clarification in the question. however, I still have the same doubt: why the LTRIM(RTRIM()) is not done before to update the other two columns?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Right()`, use `SubString()`.

Here's an example. I've tried to show each step individually to illustrate

```
; WITH x (identifier) AS (
  SELECT '258967,Sarah Jones'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '98745,Richar James '
)
SELECT identifier
     , CharIndex(',', identifier) As comma
     , SubString(identifier, CharIndex(',', identifier) + 1, 1000) As name_only
     , LTrim(RTrim(SubString(identifier, CharIndex(',', identifier) + 1, 1000))) As trimmed_name_only
FROM   x
```

Note that the `1000` used should be the maximum length of the column definition or higher e.g. if your IDENTIFIER column is a `varchar(2000)` then use 2,000 instead.